# No se me pinta todo el background del footer

Tags: html, css

Tengo un footer compuesto por 2 contenedores divs. Me sucede que cuando coloreo el footer solo se colorean los divs, y mi idea es que se coloree todo el footer. Me parece raro que esto suceda ya que a la propiedad `background-color` la pongo en el footer, no en los divs.

Adjunto código:

HTML:

```
<footer id="footer">

  
  <div id="footer_logo">
    <img src="imagenes/marca-slogan.png" alt="logo footer" height="110" width="300" id="logo_footer">

    <p id="titulo_redes_sociales">Seguinos!</p>
    <img src="imagenes/facebook.svg"width="48" height="48" alt="Facebook" class="redes_sociales">
    <img src="imagenes/instagram.svg"width="45" height="45" alt="Instagram" class="redes_sociales">
    <img src="imagenes/twitter.svg"width="45" height="45" alt="Twitter" class="redes_sociales">
    <img src="imagenes/youtube.svg" width="45" height="45" alt="Youtube" class="redes_sociales">

  </div>

  <div id="footer_contacto">
    <p>
    <img src="imagenes/ubicacion.svg" height="50" width="50" id="ubicacion">Av. Capdevila 1735 - Córdoba - Argentina
    </p>
    <p>
    <img src="imagenes/telefono.svg" height="40" width="40" id="telefono">+54 351 3015 995
    </p>
    <p>
      <img src="imagenes/arroba.svg" width="50" height="50" id="arroba">chocolatto_company@gmail.com
    </p>

    <p>
    <a href="#">
    Políticas y privacidad
    </a>
    </p>
    <p>
    <a href="#">
    Términos y condiciones
    </a>
    </p>
  </div>

</footer>
```

CSS:

```
#footer{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #EFE3DE;

}

#footer_logo{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 160px;
    background-color: #EFE3DE;
}


#titulo_redes_sociales{
    font-family: "oxygen", sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}

.redes_sociales{
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}

#footer_contacto{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: "oxygen", sans-serif;
    background-color: #EFE3DE;
}


#footer_contacto img{
    vertical-align: middle;
    justify-content: left;
}

#footer_contacto a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: underline;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;

}
```

Comment: Esto tiene que ver con las dimensiones de los margenes y del contenedor. Si quieres que todo el footer se coloree puedes poner posición absolute y moverlo al comienzo de la pagina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando  usas `float` el elemento sale del flujo normal del contenedor, por esto tu `footer` no tiene altura.

La solución simple es colocar un display:flex; al contenedor padre

```
footer{
  display:flex;
}
```

Demo:

```css
#footer{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: red;
display: flex;
}

#footer_logo{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 160px;
    background-color: #EFE3DE;
}


#titulo_redes_sociales{
    font-family: "oxygen", sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}

.redes_sociales{
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}

#footer_contacto{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: "oxygen", sans-serif;
    background-color: #EFE3DE;
}


#footer_contacto img{
    vertical-align: middle;
    justify-content: left;
}

#footer_contacto a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: underline;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;

}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">

  
  <div id="footer_logo">
    <img src="imagenes/marca-slogan.png" alt="logo footer" height="110" width="300" id="logo_footer">

    <p id="titulo_redes_sociales">Seguinos!</p>
    <img src="imagenes/facebook.svg"width="48" height="48" alt="Facebook" class="redes_sociales">
    <img src="imagenes/instagram.svg"width="45" height="45" alt="Instagram" class="redes_sociales">
    <img src="imagenes/twitter.svg"width="45" height="45" alt="Twitter" class="redes_sociales">
    <img src="imagenes/youtube.svg" width="45" height="45" alt="Youtube" class="redes_sociales">

  </div>

  <div id="footer_contacto">
    <p>
    <img src="imagenes/ubicacion.svg" height="50" width="50" id="ubicacion">Av. Capdevila 1735 - Córdoba - Argentina
    </p>
    <p>
    <img src="imagenes/telefono.svg" height="40" width="40" id="telefono">+54 351 3015 995
    </p>
    <p>
      <img src="imagenes/arroba.svg" width="50" height="50" id="arroba">chocolatto_company@gmail.com
    </p>

    <p>
    <a href="#">
    Políticas y privacidad
    </a>
    </p>
    <p>
    <a href="#">
    Términos y condiciones
    </a>
    </p>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: Ahh bien graciass no me imaginaba que era por el float